# Merging two JSON files for US Counties

Tags: json, database, datatables, jq

I have a json file that is filtered by US County and has, in the "properties" section, median income. So this json file contains median income by county.

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [
      0.035896170617061705,
      0.005347309530953095
    ],
    "translate": [
      -179.14734,
      17.884813
    ]
  },
  "objects": {
    "us_counties_20m": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [
            [
              0,
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4
            ]
          ],
          "id": "0500000US01001",
          "properties": {
            "PRICE": 48863
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [
            [
              5,
              6,
              7,
              8,
              9,
              10
            ]
          ],
          "id": "0500000US01009",
          "properties": {
            "PRICE": 41940
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [
            [
              11,
              12,
              13,
              14,
              15
            ]
          ],
          "id": "0500000US01017",
          "properties": {
            "PRICE": 33500
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [
            [
              16,
              17,
              -3,
              18,
              19,
              20,
              21
            ]
          ],
          "id": "0500000US01021",
          "properties": {
            "PRICE": 38833
          }
        },
```

I wish to add to the "properties" section another price, namely the median home price per county. So I have a second json file with data like this:

```
[
 {
   "Full County Number": 56045,
   "Price-RangeQ42019": "$150,000-$350,000",
   "Geography": "Weston County,  Wyoming",
   "Latitude (generated)": 43.8403,
   "Longitude (generated)": -104.5684,
   "Q42019 Price": "$178,218"
 },
 {
   "Full County Number": 56043,
   "Price-RangeQ42019": "$150,000-$350,000",
   "Geography": "Washakie County,  Wyoming",
   "Latitude (generated)": 43.8356,
   "Longitude (generated)": -107.6602,
   "Q42019 Price": "$170,665"
 },
```

, where I want all the categories of the 2nd json to be appended to the "properties" section as a separate category.

Desired output (the "properties" section contains more info):

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "transform": {
    "scale": [
      0.035896170617061705,
      0.005347309530953095
    ],
    "translate": [
      -179.14734,
      17.884813
    ]
  },
  "objects": {
    "us_counties_20m": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "arcs": [
            [
              0,
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4
            ]
          ],
          "id": "0500000US01001",
          "properties": {
            "PRICE": 48863
            "Price-RangeQ42019": "$150,000-$350,000",
            "Geography": "Washakie County,  Wyoming",
            "Latitude (generated)": 43.8356,
            "Longitude (generated)": -107.6602,
            "Q42019 Price": "$170,665"
          }
        },
etc...
```

The "id" and the "Full County Number" in the first and second json files match up exactly. However, the "Full County Number" lacks the "0500000US" prefix before each county. How might I merge these 2 json files to get the third json with the additional property?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Both the provided JSON are incomplete. Provide a complete JSON and a proper expected output.

Comment: I updated my desired output. The JSON files actually just continue on in their patterns (just the beginning of the 1st json file is slightly different.

Comment: @Inian here is a similar example https://jqplay.org/s/MHypDS-C64

Answer (score 1):

The following should come close to providing a solution.  First, a dictionary ($dict) is constructed, and then this dictionary is used to update the first file.

Invocation:

```
jq -n -f program.jq secondfile.json firstfile.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
def lpad:
  tostring | if length < 5 then ("00000" + .) | .[-5:] else . end;


(input
 | map( with_entries(if .key == "Full County Number" 
                     then .key = "id" | .value |= "0500000US" + lpad 
                     else .
                     end ) )
   | INDEX(.[]; .id) ) as $dict
| inputs
| .objects.us_counties_20m.geometries |= 
      map( .id as $id 
           | (.properties += $dict[$id]) )
```

Comment: The program is too long for it to be entered conveniently on the command-line. Simply copy the program into a a file using any text editor.

Comment: thank you so much! I resolved my issue. Thank you very much, again!

Comment: I need to get rid of the quotes and the dollar sign around the "Q42019 Price" entries. How might I do that? Instead of "$170,665," I need 170,665

Comment: That looks like a completely separate and well-focused question, so I'd suggest asking it accordingly.  Note, however, that `170,665` is not JSON, so if you want JSON output, you will have to choose between a JSON number and a JSON string.